# Bottle-Cork breaking?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bottle

I'm developing a website using the Bottle framework and have been using the Cork library to handle authentication.

The website is nearing completion and I have started to look into deployment. I've looked into using Gunicorn as I had heard good things but the change over has created an unusual bug that I am not sure how to remedy.

Previously, I ran my site using the inbuilt development web server but I tried to use Gunicorn instead, and this seemed to work except trying to login generated a 500 server error and this:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1740, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "/home/shaunf/PycharmProjects/final-project/bottle_app.py", line 75, in login
    aaa.login(username, password, success_redirect='/', fail_redirect='/login')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cork/cork.py", line 130, in login
    self._setup_cookie(username)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cork/cork.py", line 603, in _setup_cookie
    session['username'] = username
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

`

I tried changing back to the development server but that hasn't helped.

I'm not really sure what to try next and any ideas or hints as to what I could trouble would be really appreciated.

Comment: It looks like it isn't finding the session. Are you using beaker as session middleware? Some of your code would help provide context.

Comment: You are right. I've been away from the internet for a couple of days and have managed to solve this. I was forgetting to declare the app variable for Beaker. Thank you for your help!